# Execute a command whenever Ubuntu starts

Tags: scripts, cron

I have Ubuntu 16.04. From here [Run Scripts on Start UP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up). I followed this answer:

> One approach is to add an **@reboot** cron task:
>
> Running `crontab -e` will allow you to edit your cron.
>   Adding a line like this to it:
>
> ```
> @reboot /path/to/script
> ```
>
> will execute that script once your computer boots up.

I was successfully able to edit file `crontab`.

but I couldn't be able to save it using:

- `:q`
- `:wq`
- `CTRL+x`

None of them worked. I got this message on command `:q`:

```
No write since Last Change (add ! to override
```

- After executing command - `EDITOR=vi crontab -e`

  Output - `no crontab for admin - using an empty one`
- Again on executing command - `sudo EDITOR=vi crontab -e`

  Output - `no crontab for root - using an empty one`

Comment: If you gat that message with `:q`, then `:wq` should work.

Comment: Hi, @muru that is my point `:wq` exit the window but it not save `cron` file.

Comment: If that was your point, then *say so in the question*. What does `crontab -l` show after you edit and do `:wq`?

Comment: I mention this in my question:

* `:q`
* `:wq`
* `Ctrl+x`

None of them are work.

Comment: "None of them are work" doesn't mean anything. What do you mean by that? You did say what happened when you did `:q`, but you said nothing of the others. Without knowing what you mean by that, sentences like that are ignored as garbage.

Comment: What does `crontab -l` produce please put that in your OP!

Comment: Hi, @George `crontab -l` output `no crontab for admin`

Comment: @george  I get the impression that creating a cron job that causes a reboot may be ill-advised and beyond the current skill level of the OP.  Unless the OP's user account is admin I'd be concerned as to what cron he is actually editing.   Stuffing something like this in cron is probably not the best thing for an obviously novice user to be doing.

Comment: Is your editor `vim` or `nano`? If `nano` see update on my answer

Comment: I don't have `nano` editor. Only have `vi` editor.

Comment: How come it comes preinstalled, use `which nano` to see if its there. It should be.

Comment: Why are you using `EDITOR=vi crontab -e` please simply use `crontab -e` and let it use the default editor which I believe is `nano`

Comment: Command - `which nano`

Output - **Nothing get print**

Comment: Now that's strange, are you the original owner of the said system and did you remove it some how?

Comment: No, I am not the original owner. It's a client machine. I don't know if he remove nano or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60109/discussion-between-george-and-utkarsh-dubey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done well so far. The `No write since Last Change(add ! to override)` means you have written something and are closing without saving so the editor assumes you *don't wish to save your changes* and offers you the option of doing so with `:q!`. Now you need to use `:wq` to ensure that the changes are written then the editor is quit or exited.

Where its a `nano` editor as I noticed `crontab` uses this please do the following:

1. To save: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. To close: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: Hi, @George it shows `Not an editor command :qw`.

Comment: Updated the answer, sorry syntax error

Comment: @UtkarshDubey its `:wq` not `:qw`

Comment: @daisy I spoke with OP and the issue is sudo privileges. The original owner of the system did some awful things and lost sudo powers and other so he OP has to fixed that first.

Comment: Okay sorry i didn't checked edited answer - Your comment syntax error is about `:qw`

Comment: Thanks a lot @George, It works perfectly on Client other Ubuntu machine which have `nano` installed. And for 1st machine may be there is something wrong in machine.

Answer (score 0):

Having a cron job that causes an unexpected, immediate reboot could cause you frustration and confusion.

If you are convinced that you want to do this, the command to write and exit the editor depends on what editor you selected when you invoked the crontab -e command.

Esc :wq! or Shift ZZ will work for vi

For nano, Ctrl O followed by Ctrl X

Comment: Hi, @jones0610 How to invoke editor?

Comment: @UtkarshDubey `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`